# How to return values from dynamically generated "insert" command?

Tags: firebird

I have a stored procedure that performs inserts and updates in the tables. The need to create it was to try to centralize all the scan functions before inserting or updating records. Today the need arose to return the value of the field `ID` of the table so that my application can locate the registry and perform other stored procedures.

**Stored procedure**

```
SET TERM ^ ;

CREATE OR ALTER procedure sp_insupd (
    iaction varchar(3),
    iusuario varchar(20),
    iip varchar(15),
    imodulo varchar(30),
    ifieldsvalues varchar(2000),
    iwhere varchar(1000),
    idesclogs varchar(200))
returns (
    oid integer)
as
declare variable vdesc varchar(10000);
begin
  if (iaction = 'ins') then
  begin
    vdesc = idesclogs;

    /*** the error is on the line below ***/
    execute statement 'insert into '||:imodulo||' '||:ifieldsvalues||' returning ID into '||:oid||';';
  end else
  if (iaction = 'upd') then
  begin
    execute statement 'select '||:idesclogs||' from '||:imodulo||' where '||:iwhere into :vdesc;

    execute statement 'execute procedure SP_CREATE_AUDIT('''||:imodulo||''');';

    execute statement 'update '||:imodulo||' set '||:ifieldsvalues||' where '||:iwhere||';';
  end

  insert into LOGS(USUARIO, IP, MODULO, TIPO, DESCRICAO) values (
  :iusuario, :iip, :imodulo, (case :iaction when 'ins' then 1 when 'upd' then 2 end), :vdesc);
end^

SET TERM ; ^
```

The error in the above line is occurring due to syntax error. The procedure is compiled normally, that is, the error does not happen in the compilation, since the line in question is executed through the "execute statement". When there was no need to return the value of the `ID` field, the procedure worked normally with the line like this:

```
...
execute statement 'insert into '||:imodulo||' '||:ifieldsvalues||';';
...
```

What would be the correct way for the value of the `ID` field to be stored in the `OID` variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is REAL VALUE in `ifieldsvalues` ?

you can not have BOTH

- `'insert into '||:imodulo||' '||:ifieldsvalues`
- `'update '||:imodulo||' set '||:ifieldsvalues`

because methods to specify column names and column values in `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements is fundamentally different!!! You either would have broken update-stmt or broken insert-stmt!

> The error in the above line is occurring due to syntax error

This is not enough. Show the real error text, all of it.
It includes the actual command you generate and it seems you had generated it really wrong way.

---

> all the scan functions before inserting or updating records

Move those functions out of the SQL server and into your application server.
Then you would not have to make insert/update in that "strings splicing" way, which is VERY fragile and "SQL injection" friendly. You stepped into the road to hell here.

> the error does not happen in the compilation

Exactly. And that is only for starters. You are removing all the safety checks that should had helped you in applications development.

- http://searchsoftwarequality.techtarget.com/definition/3-tier-application
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture#Three-tier_architecture
- http://bobby-tables.com

---

On modern Firebird versions `EXECUTE STATEMENT` command can have the same `INTO` clause as PSQL `SELECT` command.

https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-psql-coding.html#fblangref25-psql-execstmt

Use http://translate.ru to read http://www.firebirdsql.su/doku.php?id=execute_statement

Or just see SQL examples there. Notice, however, those examples all use `SELECT` dynamic command, not `INSERT`. So I am not sure it would work that way.

This works in Firebird 2.5 (but not in Firebird 2.1) PSQL blocks.

```
execute statement 'insert into Z(payload) values(2) returning id' into :i;
```

To run it from IBExpert/FlameRobin/iSQL interactive shell add that obvious boilerplate:

```
execute block returns (i integer) as
begin
  execute statement 'insert into Z(payload) values(2) returning id' into :i;
  suspend;
end
```

Comment: I am making the changes according to your response. I will post the result soon. Thanks!

Comment: @CarlosAndrade well, guess I was wrong. you just have to use exec-stmt-into. exec-block is harder to combine with string variable/expression as the stmt source. Additionally, to get return values from EB you would have to run FOR EXECUTE BLOCK loop. Which is much more boilerplate

Comment: Okay, I'm trying all these possibilities.

Comment: I remember I had to use execute block within execute statement due to those restrictions :-)

Comment: Actually, the "EXECUTE BLOCK" can not be used within "Procedures".

Comment: @CarlosAndrade yes, that is why I retracted my 2nd answer, even before this your comments

Comment: Anyway I tried it did not work, I think I'm off to another alternative. I tried as follows, however unsuccessfully: `execute statement 'execute block returns (oid integer) as begin insert into TABLE (DESC) values (''Testing exec-block within exec-stmt'') returning ID into: oid ; end';`. The strange thing is that not even the "exec-block" is getting the value of the ID field. Thank you very much for the effort and time dedicated, your response was very useful for me to reach that conclusion.

Comment: @CarlosAndrade exec-block does get the value, it just does not send it out because you did not asked it to do so. You missed that part of documentation that talks about result-sets and "selectable procedures". You missed the second command in my exec-block example. Additionally you still did not said FB version and never you showed complete error text.

Comment: worked perfectly as his example `execute statement 'insert into Z(payload) values(2) returning id' into :i;`. The line of my procedure was this way and now everything okay as I expected: `execute statement 'insert into '||:modulo||' '||:ifieldsvalues||' returning ID' into :OID;`. Thank you my friend!

Comment: Just complementing your previous question ... The variable "ifieldsvalues" receives the fields and values from the respective table, as an example: `(FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME) values ('Carlos', 'Andrade')`

Comment: @CarlosAndrade and so you get `execute statement 'insert into TableName (FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME) values ('Carlos', 'Andrade')  returning ID into columnname';` - and non-doubled quotes around "Carlos" and "Andrade" break the syntax. You are on the road to hell. Rethink you requirements and ways you structure responsibilities within your programs complex

Comment: for example if that only thing you need is logging - then either add specific `AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE` trigger to every your table (you can automatize their generation) that needs logging. Or do the logging in your applications on the database connection library level. The way you do it via one only SP and dynamic SQL generation is very fragile, slow and opens potential security holes. Further you go - more unexpected corner cases will hurt you.

Comment: I understand its placement, but I do this way I still believe that it gets more centralized some procedures that I need to perform with each insertion or update of records in all the tables. One of them is to create a log in the Audit table to log the activities, it was very laborious when I did all the procedures using Triggers in each table. Not to mention that it is only one of the procedures

Comment: With regards to sending the data, my application is sending correctly with the appropriate amounts of quotes, above was just an example. I believe the way to hell goes further than that :)

Comment: If I could, I would vote more often in your response. Thanks again for the time dedicated!

Comment: Here you are making automatic generation of insert/update statements, and rather fragile implementations of them. Try instead make similar automatic program-generated creation of triggers. Same time but better structure.